# swift rotating view pause

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, animatewithduration

I want to make infinite rotation. But I see a rotating pause. Can you explain why?

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations:
        {
            self.myview.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.myview.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }, completion: { nil
        }()
    )
```

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want circular rotation of `UIView`. you can achieved using below code.

```
 CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0  * 1 * 3 ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 3;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 5;

    [btnPush.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: But this isnt infinite

Comment: @Arbitur, ya i know that but we can set `rotationAnimation.repeatCount = -1;` and increase animation duration what ever you want as per requirement.